# Longest common prefix javascript divide and conquer

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

Can anyone find the problem with this solution in javascript? It seems identical to the leetcode Java solution, but when the input is strs = ["flower","flow","flight"], I'm getting that lcpLeft is undefined when it should be "flow" and when lcpRight is "flight".

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    // divide problem up into comparisons between two elements, i.e. the base case
    
    return recursiveCommonPrefix(strs, 0, strs.length-1);
};

var recursiveCommonPrefix = function(strs, low, high){
    if(low==high) {
        return strs[low];
    }else{
        var mid = Math.floor((low+high)/2);
        //console.log(low, mid, high);
        var lcpLeft = recursiveCommonPrefix(strs, low, mid);
        var lcpRight = recursiveCommonPrefix(strs, mid+1, high);
        return baseCaseCommonPrefix(lcpLeft, lcpRight);   
    }
}

var baseCaseCommonPrefix = function(lcpLeft, lcpRight){ // common prefix between two elements
    var shorter = Math.min(lcpLeft.length, lcpRight.length);
    for(var i = 0; i<shorter; i++){
        if(lcpLeft[i]!=lcpRight[i]){
            return lcpLeft.substring(0,i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `baseCaseCommonPrefix` may fall through the `for` loop without breaking out of it with a `return`. In that case the return value will be undefined, leading to the problem you described.

This happens when `baseCaseCommonPrefix` is called with two strings, where one is a prefix of the other (or equal to it). In the example case this happens with this call:

```
baseCaseCommonPrefix("flower","flow")
```

You can fix this by adding the following line below the `for` loop:

```
return lcpLeft.substring(0, shorter);
```